# UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY zone.js@0.7.6

Tags: node.js, angular-universal

1. Installed angular2-webpack-starter by following these instructions from https://github.com/AngularClass/angular2-webpack-starter#quick-start
2. Following the instructions from https://universal.angular.io/quickstart/ 
   executed `npm install body-parser angular2-universal preboot express --save`

Output:

```
        +-- angular2-universal@2.1.0-rc.1
        | +-- angular2-platform-node@2.1.0-rc.1
        | | `-- parse5@2.2.3
        | +-- css@2.2.1
        | | +-- source-map@0.1.43
        | | +-- source-map-resolve@0.3.1
        | | | +-- atob@1.1.3
        | | | +-- resolve-url@0.2.1
        | | | `-- source-map-url@0.3.0
        | | `-- urix@0.1.0
        | +-- js-beautify@1.6.8
        | | +-- config-chain@1.1.11
        | | | `-- proto-list@1.2.4
        | | `-- editorconfig@0.13.2
        | |   `-- lru-cache@3.2.0
        | +-- parse5@2.2.3
        | `-- xhr2@0.1.4
        +-- body-parser@1.16.0
        +-- express@4.14.0
        +-- preboot@4.5.2
        `-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY zone.js@0.7.6
```

Can anyone explain what does the last line imply, what is its impact and how to solve the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means you need to npm install that module as well.  This happens when a module you've installed has a peer dependency that you haven't yet installed. Docs on the [Peer Dependency thing.](https://nodejs.org/en/blog/npm/peer-dependencies/)